# How to sort the elements of an array corresponding to elements of other array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays where the ith element of first array corresponds to the ith element of other array. That is, if I move the ith element of first array to jth position than I have to do the same for second array.

I know I can do it using `pair<int, int>` and then using the `sort` function but that is not an option.

So, I was thinking that may be the third parameter of `sort` function can be used for this purpose: Something like:

```
int a[4] = {2,3,1,0}, b[4] = {10,9,6,4};  //2 corresponds to 10, 3 corrspond to 9 and so on...

sort(a,a+10); // a = {0,1,2,3}
sort(b, b+10, compare);  //->should change b to {4,6,10,9}
```

Can it be done this way? If yes, what will be the compare function?

Comment: `std::sort` is unstable. After you sort array `a` the mapping is completely ruined. Even if you pass the mapping to the `compare` function I don't think there is a way you can update your mapping. After all the `compare` function can just say if one item should be placed before or after another item. The repositioning is done by sort algorithm and depends on your STL implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done this way. Your comparator would need to be an object that contains a mapping from the elements in b to the corresponding element in a, which you could use determine the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement compare so that it, given two elements in b, compares the corresponding elements in a. You can figure out what index something is by taking `int index = element - b;` where element is one of your items in the compare function.

I would seriously suggest using `pair<>` or a `struct/class` to hold your a, b values at the same time - saves on time as well.